# Is there an equivalent in Giraffe to Url.Content("~/")?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#-giraffe

In ASP.NET MVC, I used occasional calls such as `Url.Content("~/Some folder/")` to get the full path of different URLs.

Is there anything similar in Giraffe?

The following code comes from the default app I created with the template:

```
let layout (content: XmlNode list) =
    html [] [
        head [] [
            title []  [ encodedText "TestAccountsManager" ]
            link [ _rel  "stylesheet"
                   _type "text/css"
                   _href "/main.css" ]
        ]
        body [] content
    ]
```

Is `/main.css` relative to the root of the application? Or is it relative to the server name? In ASP.NET MVC, I would use something like `~/css/main.css`, let's say. If the app is deployed under `http://example/someapp/` or `http://example/` I know this would work in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the default Giraffe template, where static resources get put in the `WebRoot` folder, it seems to work if you use:

```
_href "./main.css"
```

This allows for deploying the web application at the root of the host, or as a "folder" one level below the root.

If you are putting the static resources in a folder below the `WebRoot`, then resources would go in the folder:

```
WebRoot\Subfolder
```

(e.g. `WebRoot\css`), and the `href` attribute would need to be changed to:

```
_href "./Subfolder/main.css
```

(e.g. `_href "./css/main.css"`)

Comment: Actually my answer is not a great one as if you  are two folders down this no longer works.  This can be seen if you use the hello/??? route from the template.  I have a feeling this may best be handled by pulling the deployment application name from the web.config file or an hosting environment property.